# Generating tree nodes on the fly

Tags: antlr, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an ANTLRv3 grammar to transform an AST (generated and consumed by other grammars).

One part of it is to rewrite ranges defined like `M:N` (i.e. `1:5`) into their actual list representation — `M, M+1, ..., N` (i.e. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

So, a node `^(RANGE s=INT e=INT)` is transformed into a list of `INT` tokens.

What I currently do now is the following:

```
range
    : ^(RANGE s=INT e=INT) -> { ToSequence(int.Parse($s.text),int.Parse($e.text)) }
    ;
```

and the `ToSequence` method looks like

```
private ITree ToSequence(int start, int end)
{
    var tree = new CommonTree();

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        tree.AddChild(new CommonTree(new CommonToken(INT, i.ToString())));
    }

    return tree;
}
```

It actually works fine, transforming tree node `(TIME 1 2 (RANGE 5 10) 3 4)` to `(TIME 1 2 5 6 7 8 9 10 3 4)`, but I somewhat unsure whether it is the correct and idiomatic way to do such a transformation.

So, is there any more civilized way to perform this task?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that performing such transformations inside the parser is a good idea at all. Your code lacks any kind of validity check. What if the first number is bigger than the second one? And what if errors are detected at the next stage of processing? At that point you have already lost the knowledge about the true structure of your input so you can’t give useful error messages.

I strongly recommend building a tree reflecting the true structure of your input first and transforming the tree afterwards. The transformed node might keep references to their source nodes then.

Comment: Hi! That is not performed inside the parser. I have a parser, a transformer and a consumer. The error checks were removed for the sake of simplicity — I have a problem with ANTLR here, not with lack of error checking.

Comment: So, I actually _transform the tree afterwards_ here, and just need to make the code cleaner.

Comment: @Iaroslav Kovtunenko If you’re convinced that the code is clean you don’t need to change anything. To me it doesn’t look like that. But that’s just my 2 cent. If your question contained more real application specific information/code I were able to give you more practical solutions.

Comment: the part of code I am not sure is related to ANTLR: tree node construction, token construction, returning it as ITree/CommonTree/object etc. So, I actually wonder if I do this part correctly or there are better ways to implement it — say, static helpers I am not aware of.